# Any way to have hardware accelerated virtualization without changing HW?

Tags: android-sdk, hardware-acceleration, hardware-requirements

when I installed Android Studio on my Windows box, at the end of installation it told me 
"Android SDK is up to date"
but it complained that
"your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization".
Then it listed some alternative options.  Looks like this is because my native HW has non-Intel (AMD) CPUs.

So my question to Android developers is, 
does anyone know of a way to have hardware accelerated virtualization without changing my PC hardware?

Comment: Thanks @GiantTree. Could you submit that as an answer rather than a comment? Useful info I think, that other users would be interested in seeing in an answer where it would more easily be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't.
Your best bet would be a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox but this is more like hoping for it to work and not break after installing.

The reason is [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) that is building on Intel's virtualization technology, VirtualBox also supports AMD's virtualization technology and should be better than using no hardware acceleration at all.